# Connect-PnPOnline -PnPO365ManagementShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp

I am trying to connect to PnPOnline using the following

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://Company.sharepoint.com/sites/testclientsite -PnPO365ManagementShell -LaunchBrowser
```

After authenticating through the browser, I keep receiving the error:

> Token receivedConnect-PnPOnline : The handle is invalid.

I have tried with and without the `-LaunchBrowser`. I have restarted everything possible. I have all the proper permissions and it works using `-useweblogin`, but that keeps losing token after a group or two are created. I receive a The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. Any help would be appreciated.

***Update*** 7/2/2019

I am on SharePoint PnP PowerShell Online version: 3.10.1906.0 
I am on SharePoint Online Management Shell version: 16.0.8924.1200

I know the code is correct because I would get an invalid code in the authentication window. The error comes after the token is received. Still and issue. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the [SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=35588).

Download and install the [SharePoint PnP PowerShell Online](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases/download/3.10.1906.0/SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline.msi).

Then open the SharePoint Online Management Shell, and run your command again. Mark sure enter the right code provide in the SharePoint Online Management Shell.

It working fine in my test.

[image]

Comment: I have done all of this. 

I am on SharePoint PnP PowerShell Online version: 3.10.1906.0

I am on SharePoint Online Management Shell version: 16.0.8924.1200

I know the code is correct because I would get an invalid code in the authentication window. The error comes after the token is received. Still and issue.